# What is the earliest use of the "this" keyword in any programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, history, object-oriented

I understand the `this` (or `self` or `Me`) is used to refer to the current object, and that it is a feature of object-oriented programming languages. The earliest language I could find which has such a concept was Smalltalk, which uses `self` but was wondering where and when (which programming language) the concept was first implemented?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Simula 67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) is generally considered the first object-oriented language and predates [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) [by a number of years](http://worrydream.com/EarlyHistoryOfSmalltalk/).

It also used the `this` keyword for the same concept, which can be seen in [this book chapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20040923043932/http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/bookhtml/chap13.html) extract:

```
  class Linker;
  begin
     ref(Linker) Next, Sex, Employment;
     text ID;

     procedure Add_to_List(LHead); name LHead; ref(Linker) LHead;
     begin
        Next :- LHead;
        LHead :- this Linker
     end..of..Add..to..List;

     procedure Onto_Lists(Gender,Occupation);
         name Gender,Occupation;
         ref(Linker) Gender,Occupation;
     begin
        Sex :- Gender;
        Employment :- Occupation;
        Gender :- Occupation :- this Linker
     end..of..Onto..Lists;

     InImage;
     ID :- Copy(SysIn.Image);
     InImage;
  end--of--Linker;
```

Comment: Interesting! What's up with those `end..` and `end--` bits? Do they constitute part of the syntax?

Comment: @jogloran: The Vim syntax-highlighting rules for Simula says: "Text between the keyword 'end' and either a semicolon or one of the keywords 'end', 'else', 'when' or 'otherwise' is also a comment." \[[link](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/simula.vim#L18-L19)\] That's obviously not authoritative -- it just means that Vim would color the `..of..Onto..Lists` and `--of--Linker` and so on as comments -- but judging from the examples in the book chapter and elsewhere, I think that they are indeed optional comments (albeit not wholly freeform).

Comment: FWIW, a book I have here called "Introduction to Simula 67" gives the same rule as the Vim rule set mentioned by @ruakh, i.e. comments can directly follow the keyword `END` but may not contain any of the following: `;`, `END`, `WHEN`, `OTHERWISE`, `ELSE`. Comments in the block body need to start with the keyword `COMMENT`.

Comment: @njuffa You are correct --- Simula67 used the old Algol60 comment style. I haven't used Simula67 since the 1970s though. It was in some ways more advanced than C++ which was an attempt to implement as much of Simula67 as possible using C. But Simula67 had coroutines which did not make it into C++.

Comment: Nitpick: Smalltalk-80 was the first generally available version but Smalltalk-71 was the first iteration: http://worrydream.com/EarlyHistoryOfSmalltalk/

Comment: @user3810626 Excellent reference. Thanks for the comment